# Random flashing occurring only on Galaxy Note 4

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, samsung-mobile, galaxy

For some reason I have found a glitch that makes no sense at all and only appears on the Galaxy Note 4, as I think now. The only test devices I have is a Nexus 7 (2012), blue stacks beta and the Note 4. This glitch only is appearing on the note 4. Here is the drawing code:

```
if(!started){
            continue;
        }
        h = getHolder();
        if (!h.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }
        Canvas c = h.lockCanvas();
        c.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), white);

        //draw walls
        for(int i=0;i<walls.length;i++){
            c.drawRect(walls[i].x, walls[i].y, walls[i].bottom, walls[i].right, red);
        }

        //draw portals
        for(int i=0;i<portals.length;i++){
            Log.d("S", i+"");
            Log.d("S", portalimages[i].toString());
            c.drawBitmap(portalimages[i], portals[i].x1, portals[i].y1, null);
            c.drawBitmap(portalimages[i], portals[i].x2, portals[i].y2, null);
        }

        //draw startlocations
        for(int i=0;i<startlocations.length;i++){
            c.drawBitmap(player, startlocations[i].x, startlocations[i].y, null);
        }

        //draw checkpoints
        for(int i=0;i<checkpoints.length;i++){
            c.drawRect(checkpoints[i].x, checkpoints[i].y, checkpoints[i].x+this.getHeight()/18, checkpoints[i].y+this.getHeight()/18, blue);
        }

        //draw middle line
        c.drawRect(0, getHeight()/2-getHeight()/80, getWidth(), getHeight()/2+getHeight()/80, black);

        menu.draw(c);

        h.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

The glitch happens once my onClick is called. it just adds a new startlocation:

```
startlocations[location] = new Coord(lastx, lasty);
if(location>0){
    location = 0;
}else{
    location++;
}
break;
```

Note: startlocations is setup with `startlocations = new Coord[2];`

Sorry for the video quality. The Note 4 is my Dad's so I had to send it over a messaging service and it compressed it, then YouTube compressed it more. Then it breaks out into this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ig9mflYBPaI

There is nothing else that changes on click of the player start locations button. I will try to look more into this but I decided to post it here in case I missed something. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I now know that the problem goes away when you do not have this line : `c.drawBitmap(player, startlocations[i].x, startlocations[i].y, null);` which makes no sense. There is no error and it is loaded with this code. `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.portal);` and later is adjusted with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(player, this.getHeight()/18, this.getHeight()/18, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it makes NO sense at all. For some reason, just in this class, the image needs to have transparency or else it glitches. Later on I draw other non transparent images. It makes no sense but it works. please tell me if you know any reason why this happens.

My guess is that in the other class I used the main package but in this class it's a different package. This could be the reason why it's only this class (or method). I'll have to do more testing.

Thanks.